# Help optimizing this query with multiple where exists

Tags: optimization, sql, postgresql

In the application I'm building, the user is able to define 'types' where each 'type' has a set of 'attributes'.

The user is able to create instances of products by defining a value for each attribute the product's type has.

A pic of the schema:
[image: A pic of the schema]

I'm creating the query where the user specifies the attributes values and the product type and with that I should return all the product id's that meets the query.

The problem I see in my query is that I'm performing a whole `select * from attributes_products ...` for each attribute that the product's type has.

Is there a way to optimize this?
If I create an index in the column attributes_products.product_id would this query be actually optimal?

Example of a query where I'm looking for a product whose type has 3 attributes:

```
select p.id
from Products as p
where 
exists(
    select * from attributes_products
    where
        product_id = p.id AND
        attribute_id = 27 AND
        value = 'some_value'
) AND
exists(
    select * from attributes_products
    where
        product_id = p.id AND
        attribute_id = 28 AND
        value = 'other_value'
) AND
exists(
    select * from attributes_products
    where
        product_id = p.id AND
        attribute_id = 29 AND
        value = 'oother_value'
)
```

Many thanks.

## **Conclusions**

So, Gareth Rees (selected answer) proposed another solution which involves multiple Joins.
Here is the explanation of its query (done by PGAdmin):
[image: Selected answer query explanation]

This is the explanation of the original query:
[image: Original query]

I believe that the selected answer is slightly faster, but consumes a lot more memory (because of the triple join).
I believe that my original query is slightly slower (very slightly, since there's an index on the attributes_products table) but a lot more efficient in memory.

Comment: what Database Engine are you using?

Comment: @Malachi, I'm using PostgreSQL as database manager/engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL allows you to join the same table multiple times, so what you need here is:

```
SELECT p.id FROM products AS p
JOIN attributes_products AS ap1
  ON ap1.product_id = p.id AND ap1.attribute_id = 27 AND ap1.value = '...'
JOIN attributes_products AS ap2
  ON ap2.product_id = p.id AND ap2.attribute_id = 28 AND ap2.value = '...'
JOIN attributes_products AS ap3
  ON ap3.product_id = p.id AND ap3.attribute_id = 29 AND ap3.value = '...'
```

Here's the toy MySQL database that I'm using to answer this question:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
CREATE TABLE attributes_products (
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    attribute_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value CHAR(40)
);
CREATE INDEX ap_product ON attributes_products (product_id);
CREATE INDEX ap_attribute ON attributes_products (attribute_id);

INSERT INTO products VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO attributes_products VALUES (1, 27, 'a');
INSERT INTO attributes_products VALUES (1, 28, 'b');
INSERT INTO attributes_products VALUES (1, 29, 'c');
```

With my query above, MySQL reports the following query plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap1   | ref    | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const               |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap2   | ref    | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const               |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap3   | ref    | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const               |    1 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY      | 4       | temp.ap3.product_id |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

[See the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) for an explanation of the `EXPLAIN` output.

This looks better than the plan for the OP's query:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table               | type  | possible_keys           | key          | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p                   | index | NULL                    | PRIMARY      | 4       | NULL  |    2 | Using where; Using index |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | attributes_products | ref   | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const |    1 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | attributes_products | ref   | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const |    1 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | attributes_products | ref   | ap_product,ap_attribute | ap_attribute | 4       | const |    1 | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

But results will vary from one database to another: a good query planner might be able to make something efficient out of the OP's query.

Comment: wouldn't this still bog down a little bit? I mean not as much as the original but it would still bog down wouldn't it?

Comment: It all depends on the query planner, but with indexes on `attributes_products.product_id` and `attributes_products.attribute_id` MySQL looks like it has a decent plan. Try it on your preferred database and see for yourself.

Comment: I just assumed this was SQL Server, I didn't even look for tags...oops

Comment: But what if I create an index in the attributes_products table on the product_id. Yes, my query is doing multiple subqueries, but I think that they would take minimum time given the index I'm talking about; in exchange of that, my query doesn't consumes too much memory. I think (but correct me if I'm wrong) that your query would be slightly faster, but it will hold a bunch of memory for the inner join.

Comment: There's no substitute for trying both and seeing which is better!